# How to format float number to x amount of decimals in java

Tags: java, decimalformat

I need to format this float so the label will display x amount of decimals.
ex.10.9832432 I want it to display 10.9832432 the exact number of decimals there is.

```
    try{
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
    float numOne = Float.parseFloat(numberOne.getText());
    float numTwo = Float.parseFloat(numberTwo.getText());
    float anser = numOne+numTwo;
    String AR = df.format(anser);
        answerLabel.setText(AR);
    }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        answerLabel.setText(null);
    }
```

Comment: `float` only has 6 digits of precision, I suggest using `double` or `BigDecimal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well then.... you should tell your code not to display it as a string representation of a integer like you do with your declaration of the **df** variable using the **DecimalFormat** class.

If you want your label to display your actual supplied sum of floats then don't even bother to use DecimalFormat unless you really want to display an actual specific String format. The following will do what is required:

```
    float numOne = Float.parseFloat(numberOne.getText());
    float numTwo = Float.parseFloat(numberTwo.getText());
    float anser = numOne+numTwo;
    String AR = String.valueOf(anser);
    answerLabel.setText(AR);
```

But if you **do** want to display a specific string format (let's say to display the sum to a precision of 3 decimal places) then by all means, use **DecimalFormat** but in this fashion:

```
try{
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###"); // provide the format you actually want.
    float numOne = Float.parseFloat(numberOne.getText());
    float numTwo = Float.parseFloat(numberTwo.getText());
    float anser = numOne+numTwo;
    String AR = df.format(anser);
    answerLabel.setText(AR);
}
catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
    answerLabel.setText(null);
}
```